# DAX CALCULATE ALL

Tags: dax

I am new to programming with Dax. Why doesn't the bottom table, which has *Q5_2 Let at få aftale Total* as values, show 8684 for all table rows, when it has been ALL'd in the measure ??

[image: dax calculate all visual]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The function `ALL()` removes filters from a table or column. However, if applied on a column, only filters for that specific column are removed; other filters might still be in effect. I'm guessing that Power BI has problems with the special character in your column name, because I can see only one column and your measure in the table.

Here is an example of how removing the filter from the column should return the total amount of rows in that table:

[image: ALL applied on a column]

If you add an additional column to the table though, data is filtered by the second column as well, bypassing the `ALL()` on the first column:

[image: ALL applied on a column, but data is filtered by second column bypassing the ALL]

Now to solve your problem: you could write `ALL(Data)` instead of `ALL(Data[Q5_2 Let at få aftale])`, removing filters from the whole table and not just the whole column.

But also, I don't see why you would need `CALCULATE()` here. You can make the measures even shorter:

- Number of all rows, regardless of filters: `COUNTROWS(ALL(Data))`
- Number of rows, filters applied: `COUNTROWS(Data)`